# ZOHO Report API - Bulk import using CSV

Tags: ruby, zoho

I am trying to do a bulk import using CSV. I'm coding in ruby So using RestClient gem for calling the Zoho Report API. How should I pass the value for ZOHO_FILE? I tried

```
RestClient.post(ZOHO_REPORT_API, {ZOHO_FILE => File.open("path/to/csvfile")})
```

But its not working. The error which I'm getting is `The file content is not \"multipart\/form-data\" format.`

Please help me to find out the right way to pass ZOHO_FILE value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for the same.

ZOHO provides an uploading tool for the same. Its easy to understand and implement. Please have a look at [ZOHO Upload Tool](https://reports.wiki.zoho.com/Uploading-data-from-CSV-files-console-mode.html)